# Loganalysing of Innovapone using Elasticstack

Tags: logging, elastic-stack, elk

I have been tasked to build a loganalysing tool to create reports for HR of our phone usage. We have an Innovaphone IP6010 on site, that transfers its logs via GET requests to an apache webserver.
I'm currently trying to extract all usefull information out of the apache access logs, which contain the request body, which contains the log itself. The software stack I'm using consists of Elasticsearch, Kibana and Filebeat on Debian 10. I'm trying to leverage the ingest pipeline feature of filebeat to do the log analysis using a grok filter.

Log example:

```
/zz?event=A:Rel&time=1619596558&ts=5421116.946&date=20210428-075558&ref=9a9cdbc6138960015dfe00903329048b&dir=in&src_if=SIP1&dst_if=PRI2&src_cgpn=5961421358662&src_cdpn=0586583149&dst_cgpn=5961421358662&dst_cdpn=586583149&bcaps=03_90_90_a3&xcoder=G711A,20(3,0,6)&rcoder=G711A,20(0,0,7)&xstats=3+4+0+0+6&rstats=0+0+0+0+7&alert_time=1619596230&connect_time=1619596233&disc_time=1619596558&srv_id=00903329048b
```

Current grok filter (taken out of filebeat's pipiline.yml file at /usr/share/filebeat/module/apache/access/ingest):

```
- grok:
    field: url.original
    ignore_missing: false
    patterns:
    - '%{CONN_TIME:conntime}'
    - '%{DISC_TIME:disctime}'
    - '%{ALERT_TIME:alerttime}'
    - '%{SOURCE:source}'
    - '%{TARGET:target}'
    - '%{EVENT_TYPE:eventtype}'
    pattern_definitions:
      CONN_TIME: "((?<=connect_time=)([0-9]*))"
      DISC_TIME: "((?<=disc_time=)[0-9]*)"
      ALERT_TIME: "((?<=alert_time=)([0-9]*))"
      SOURCE: "((?<=src_cdpn=)[0-9]*)"
      TARGET: "((?<=src_cgpn=)[0-9]*)"
      EVENT_TYPE: "((?<=event=)[A-Z]*)"
```

My current problem is that is can't figure out why i can't access the fields in Kibana when trying to make a new dashboard. The fields aren't there even if i get the console output for match_all for the corresponding index. Any help would be more than welcome.

**Update 1**

I found out that grok exits after it finds the first hit, based on the patterns. You have to split them out into individual grok filters to get all the fields. Here is my new config that solves my problem:

```
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
    - '%{CONN_TIME:innova.conntime}'
    pattern_definitions:
      CONN_TIME: "((?<=connect_time=)([0-9]*))"
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
     - '%{DISC_TIME:innova.disctime}'
    pattern_definitions:
      DISC_TIME: "((?<=disc_time=)[0-9]*)"
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
    - '%{ALERT_TIME:innova.alerttime}'
    pattern_definitions:
      ALERT_TIME: "((?<=alert_time=)([0-9]*))"
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
    - '%{SOURCE:innova.source}'
    pattern_definitions:
      SOURCE: "((?<=src_cdpn=)[0-9]*)"
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
    - '%{TARGET:innova.target}'
    pattern_definitions:
      TARGET: "((?<=src_cgpn=)[0-9]*)"
- grok:
    ignore_missing: true
    field: message
    patterns:
    - '%{EVENT_TYPE:innova.eventtype}'
    pattern_definitions:
       EVENT_TYPE: "((?<=event=)[A-Z]*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is the one found in the original post under Update 1